# copy inside system command in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to use the perl `system()` command to copy all text files from the folder `test_folder`.

```
system("cp","/computer/myname/Desktop/test_folder/*.txt","./");
```

This works if I replace the `*` with some specific file name, but I want to copy all the `.txt` files in one shot.

The error I get is

```
cp: cannot stat '/computer/myname/Desktop/test_folder/*.txt' no such file or directory
```

Comment: In general, avoid `system` when Perl provides a built-in equivalent (or core module). See [File::Copy](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) and [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) for a more portable approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix, it's the shell that expands * into a list of files. From Perl you have to do the same, for example with:

```
system("cp", </computer/myname/Desktop/test_folder/*.txt> ,"./");
```

It would be even better to use a standard module such as [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) instead of executing an external command.

Comment: using <..> did not work, got the following error cp: missing destination file operand after `./' Also I am trying to run a few other commands like rm, find, mv, make etc from within the perl program itself so I thought system() was my only refuge.

Comment: cp: missing destination file operand after `./'

Comment: "missing destination file operand" means that you are executing `cp ./`. This happens if the glob is expanded to nothing, that is, there are no .txt files in that directory or the contents of the directory can't be listed because of usre permissions. Is this the exact code you have, you don't have the path stored in a variable or anything like that?

Comment: Sorry, my bad using <..> actually worked, I had a typo. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Using [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html):

```
use File::Copy;

copy($_, './') for (</computer/myname/Desktop/test_folder/*.txt>);
```

Comment: File::Copy might solve this problem, but I am trying to run a few other commands like rm, find, mv, make etc from within the perl program itself so I thought system() might be a good general command to use.

Comment: perl has equivalents for each of those.  I'd personally use perl rather than running to the OS.

Comment: +1 The benefit of this approach, besides being more efficient and more portable and all that, is that you can handle exceptions. Which you should. `copy($_, '.') or die "Cannot copy $_: $!"`.